# How to stream logs from elk stack to python

Tags: python, elastic-stack

I have a kafka consumer in python to process log data (stacktrace analysis and automatic issue creation) and we are also using elk stack in parallel. Is there any possibility to stream logs to python via elk to get rid of kafka? I have no experience in elk and can't find anything about streaming from it. Seems that I can just query log data once per time but this doesn't seem a perfect decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot stream data out of Elasticsearch on its own.

If your input is something else, you can use Logstash's various output plugins (or write your own) that can write into a supported Python library

For example: pipe, tcp, websocket/http, exec plugins are all generic enough to be used with any language

**However**, logstash does not persist events like Kafka does, so if you want something that can handle back pressure and doesn't drop events, you'd keep Kafka around